# how-to find out the 3-rd directory up from a batch script based on itself - %0

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

This works when the file is called from the same directory where it it is placed:

```
    @ECHO OFF
    set _MyCurrentPath=%CD%
    pushd ..
    set _Level1UpDir=%CD%
    ECHO _Level1UpDir: %_Level1UpDir%
    pushd ..
    set _Level2UpDir=%CD%
    ECHO _Level2UpDir: %_Level2UpDir%
    pushd ..
    set _Level3UpDir=%CD%
    ECHO _Level3UpDir: %_Level3UpDir%
    PAUSE
```

Yet how-to get the n-th level up just from the %0 ... it would requre some fancy call with for /f %%in

My strategy was to count the number of backslashes and the a second for loop as follows: 
    SET count=1
    FOR /f "tokens=1-4 delims=." %%G IN ('echo %0') DO (call :subroutine "%%G")
    GOTO :eof

```
:subroutine
echo %count%:%1
set /a count+=1
pause
GOTO :eof
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's wrong with the path `.\..\..\..` (repeat `..` as much as you like, in a loop) ?

Here is batch [code to repeat a string N times](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Repeat_a_string#Batch_File)

If you need the fully expanded path, you could try [tilde-expansion](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/percent.mspx?mfr=true). Eg: `%~dp0` will be `%0` expanded to a full path.

I often put `CD %~dp0` near the top of my batch files if they contain paths relative to the batch file itself.

Thus you could use `%~dp0\..\..\..` to get the full path and then 3 up from there.

Comment: *** What's wrong with the path .\..\..\.. (repeat .. as much as you like, in a loop)

Comment: It would not work if the batch file would be called from other than its current dir

Comment: Then what about using that in combination with `%~dp0` ?

Comment: Absolutely correct !!! Thanks for the good answer + the n-time repetition link :)

Answer (score 1):

Just to make copy paste live easier: This was the shortest solution I found , based on the replay of jwd:

```
cd %~dp0
for /L %%i in (1,1,3) do pushd ..
set _MyDir3LevelsUp=%CD%
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            @echo off
            ::File:FileCounter.cmd how-to count from for loop in cmd


            SET count=1
            FOR /L %%G IN (1,1,3) DO (call :LabelGoUpOnce "%%G")
            echo Hit a key to continue

            echo Dir3LevelsUp %Dir3LevelsUp%

            pause >nul
            GOTO :eof
            :LabelGoUpOnce
            pushd ..
            echo CD IS %CD%
            set Dir3LevelsUp=%CD%
            echo %count%:%1

            set /a count+=1
            GOTO :eof
```